Can we implement two CI/CD pipelines for different branches of the same repository?
Question:
Can we create two CI/CD pipelines for two branches in the same repository?
I have set up two YML files:

deploy.yml for the master branch (deploys to /var/www/html/test-main)
deploy-staging.yml for the staging branch (deploys to /var/www/html/test-staging)

When changes are pushed to staging, they deploy to test-staging, and master reflects on test-main.
Questions:

Is this a good approach?
For new development, should developers create branches from master or staging?

If from master, merging into staging requires merging back to master later.
Or should staging always merge into master after review?



What is the best branching strategy for this setup?

Yes, you can create multiple pipelines for different branches on the same repository. This is useful when you want to have multiple testing environments for different departments. One common schema for this is to have these:
Local development -> Q&A Team testing -> User acceptance testing -> Preprod integration -> Production
Usually these are different servers, but if you don't have multiple servers at your disposal I guess you can create multiple instances on the same machine.
As for the other questions:

Yes, is a good approach if you need multiple testing instances that should not interact with others instances ( be mindful that this requires different persistence storage for each instance ).

There are many strategies here. For new branch you have to ask yourself "Is this feature related to anything from staging branch or is separate ?". If is related, you make a branch from stagging, else you make it from master.


Also as a side note, I see that both master and stagging deploy to a test environment ( deducted from name ). Where will be the production code kept ? You need a base branch which holds the currently deployed to production code in case you need to redeploy after a failure or to make a hotfix. Most common strategy is to keep master as production branch and make one or multiple release branches, which I think would fit for your stagging branches.

Suppose i have to deploy feature branch changes to staging(staging branch) first. and then that feature branch changes on prod(master branch). How to deal with conflicts , rebase of all branches?

I am not really sure what you mean here. The workflow should be the same for any situation. You make changes to one branch. Then open a Pull Request to merge your feature branch into stagging, after testing is done, you open a PR to merge staging branch into master. In case of different features, if one gets to master before the other, it's still the same workflow, as long as you keep to mind to either rebase or merge before each PR. I use mostly merge because of prefference. Here is a great documentation of both. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing
